# How to sell pictures using in-app purchases on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I've created an android app and I want to sell my wallpapers/pictures. I want my users to be shown a screen where they can view my images and decide whether they want to purchased them or not

Comment: as how to do in-app purchases with images I think it would work in a very similar way as if those were pretty much any other item, think about images as being objects which have an id, an url that points to the content(the image itself), you probably need to set up a backend for that, and have a db with the urls of the images and the users registered in your app and the active purchases so you can give permission to access the images to only the users that have actually bought access to them, hope this is helpful if have questions don't hesitate to ask

Comment: Do you know any tutorials that can help with this?

Comment: Never mind. I found a solution